# Connecting IBAction in View Controller to Tab Bar Controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ibaction

For a Tab Bar app:

Using Interface Builder I am having a miserable time making a connection from a Tab Bar View to a IBAction in a File View Controller.

I believe the basics are simple; namely, control-drag from a Controller to a View to generate a IBOutlet and control-drag from a View to a Controller to generate a IBAction.

I have written

```
-(IBAction )some:(id)sender;
```

in the FirstViewController.h and

```
-(IBAction )some:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"some");
}
```

in FirstViewController.m

When I click on MainWindow.xib and then control-click on First View Controller under Tab Bar Controller I see the "Received Actions some".

But, I do not see "some" in the Console after I run the iApp.

A much more basic question that will definitely show my ignorance, but I'll take a chance:

If I control-drag from the First View Controller when MainWindow.xib is showing over to the .m source folder and rest over -(IBAction )some {...}, shouldn't I see a popup or something that says connect.

John Love

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `IBAction`? The `UITabBarController` will handle the user taps in the tab button by itself. You just need to specify the name of your XIB in order to make the tab work.

Comment: You're right .. I just added the IBAction stuff to each -viewDidLoad

Comment: What do you mean by "IBAction stuff"?